# Multi window screen gets hidden

Tags: android

When i put my app in multi window mode(Image1) and then press HOME button there, the half screen slides up so that only the status bar of that `Activity` is visible now(Image2). 
When the `Activity` transitions from the first to second image, there is no Activity lifecycle callbacks received like `onStop` or `onResume`.  I have a video playing on the `Activity` and i would like to pause the video when my `Activity` goes to the second phase because the video is not visible now.

1.How can i achieve that?

2.Also a `View` is visible on  the `Activity` in the  first image and that `View` is not visible in the second image(because the `Activity` has slided up), using `view.getGlobalVisibleRect` on that `View` always returns TRUE in the second case also. How can i determine that the `View` has been hidden in the second case?

[image: Image1]                                                                    [image: Image2]

Comment: The official docs say that onStop() should be called , did you debug it? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#lifecycle

Comment: @HristoStoyanov: Really? Do you have a link for this? It doesn't work, [when I last tried it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/28/split-screen-not-all-homes-are-created-equal.html), [a Googler says that there is no callback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39738050/115145), and so [I filed an issue to try to get a callback added for this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223943). Now, that was all with 7.0, and so it is possible that 7.1 changed things.

Comment: @HristoStoyanov Its not written anywhere in the doc that you pointed that `onStop()` has to be called.

Comment: > Note: In multi-window mode, an app can be in the paused state and still be visible to the user. An app might need to continue its activities even while paused. For example, a video-playing app that is in paused mode but is visible should continue showing its video. For this reason, we recommend that activities that play video not pause the video in their onPause() handlers. Instead, they should pause video in onStop(), and resume playback in onStart().

Comment: @HristoStoyanov: That does not address the scenario being described here. With ordinary navigation, `onStop()` will be called. In this particular "transient HOME" scenario, it is not, and that is the crux of the issue.